# How do I get a value from the referrer page in a redirect scenario

Tags: javascript, asp.net, oauth

I am working on a small project at work to pull values from a cloud based system.  It uses an oauth authentication.

I can send an authorization request and receive the token from the server on redirect.  I get the token use location.hash.

I can see in Fiddler that if I choose Approve or Deny on the authorization page, Approve/Deny is true in that web page form.  My issue is, when the automatic redirect happens, back to my page, I cannot figure out how to get that value. The Approve and Deny both return a valid token so I am struggling to figure out how to know that I pressed Deny vs Approved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When the server issues a redirect, it tears down the current page/request state, and when the next page loads, all of that data will no longer exist.  If you need to preserve some sort of variable between pages, you have a few choices:

1. Add the value as a querystring parameter to the target URL in the redirect.
2. Store the value in a cookie or in session state
3. Use `Server.Transfer` instead of redirecting.

If the first page in your flow posts to a third party page, and you need to retain data for when the flow comes back to your site, here's a couple options:

1. The first page in your flow posts to a page in your *own* site, passing the data you need in a form/post.  Your server then reads the data and either stores the data in a cookie or in session state.  It then immediately redirects to the third party service.  When the service comes back, any data stored will still exist in your own cookie or session.
2. Javascript on your page sets a cookie before posting to the third party site.  The cookie can be read when the flow returns to your page.

Comment: The authorizing page is on the web service website and I cannot modify what they send back to me.  I would have expected, when I logged in and choose "Deny", that I would get some message or error back from the webservice saying so.  Instead, it returns a valid auth token for Approve or Deny.  The API for the webservice is very poorly documented.  For other services like Google, Facebook etc.  They give you a message if you choose Deny on the login.

Comment: Edited to accommodate the additional design constraint.

Comment: Not sure if I am explaining myself well.  The api on the webservice sets up a auth scenario that I can use to access their api.  When I create the defintion on their site I give a redirect URL and a name and they create an auth code that I pass to the api to get a 15 minute authorization to perform an api operation on their webserver/webservice.

Comment: I send the request and it asks me to login.  If my login succeds they ask me to Approve or Deny the request.  They then redirect me to the URL I specified when I created the API auth scenario on their server.  I want to know if the user pressed Approve or Deny on their server.  Their server returns a 15 minute authorization that I can use but doesnt seem to return or respond differently to Approve or Deny.  I either don't understand the issue or I need to get them to respond to my support questions with some more specifics.  Thanks for the feedback & sorry if my question is a bit amateurish.